# Does anyone know which set included a 2 piece moon?

Tags: set-identification

I have a 2 piece moonlike miniset that apparently came included in some sort of larger space set. Anyone know what I'm talking about and where it comes from?

The collection includes a rocketship base with light-up and sound rockets. I assume its the same set as the moon. It's definitely not a Star Wars set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the [Countdown Corner](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6454-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D) and [Mission Control](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6456-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D) sets included both a "Light and Sound" rocket and a multi-part "moon" in the form of the "[Rock Arctic Globe](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30342c01&idColor=10#T=I&C=10)":

[image: Rock Arctic Globe from BrickLink]

Comment: Yes! It was countdown corner! Thanks! (I also have the side satellite-like pieces.)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean something like this, a 11x11 ball

[image]

Then this link gives each pass and you can click through and find all the sets they came in https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Cylinder%20Hemisphere%2011%20x%2011#T=A

They have been used for moons, planets and a deathstar